# Foreign key not updated with OneToMany

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, foreign-keys, one-to-many

I am having a simple OneToMany relation for Shopping Order and Order Items where an Order contains a list of OrderItems, I need to persist the Order and OrderItems to the corresponding DB tables.
The OrderItems table has foreign key to Orders table (a column called ORDER_ID)

**My problem is that the value in ORDER_ID column (the FK) is not updated with the order id inserted in ORDERS table, It's left as null instead**

here is the related code for Order Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORDERS")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="ORDER_ID")
private int orderId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="MEMBER_ID")
private Member member;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="order")
private List<OrderItem> orderItems;
}
```

and the related code for ItemOrder:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ORDER_ITEMS")
public class OrderItem {

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "ORDER_ID")
private Order order;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ITEM_ID")
private Item item;
}
```

N.B : the Entities annotated with OneToOne are stored correctly ,no problem
I am using hibernate 4.1.9 with MySQL

EDIT : 
I found the problem, It was actually in the code portion filling the enitie :

```
Member m = new Member();
    Order o = new Order();
    m.setMemberId(1);
    o.setMember(m);
    List<OrderItem> l = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();
    Item i = new Item();
    i.setItemId(2);
    OrderItem oI1 = new OrderItem();
    oI1.setItem(i);
    oI1.setOrder(o); // Adding this line solved the problem
    oI1.setQuantity(10);
    oI1.setTotal(100);
    OrderItem oI2 = new OrderItem();
    oI2.setItem(i);
    oI2.setOrder(o); // Adding this line solved the problem
    oI2.setQuantity(20);
    oI2.setTotal(200);
    l.add(oI2);
    l.add(oI1);
    o.setOrderItems(l);
```

you can check the line commented // Adding this line solved the problem

My question now : Is this mandatory ? Do I really need to add Parent to Child as well as add the list of children to parent ? can't I tell hibernate to do it somehow ?

can any one tell me what is wrong here ?
thanks

Comment: Nobody can without guessing, because you haven't posted the code that doesn't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: @JB Nizet  I added it now

Comment: Yes, it's mandatory. The many side is the owner side of the association. That's the one you MUST modify. The one side is the inverse side of the association (it has the `mappedBy` attribute). Modifying this side is optional.